# iOS: Creating a Text Area with Clickable hashtags and usernames

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilabel, uitextview

I'm trying to create a view with text that contains clickable hashtags (#abc) and usernames (@xyz). Initially I subclassed UILabel and although I got it working, the area was only clickable if the text was at a range less that 102 characters in (the boundingRectForCharacterRange function below started returning {0, 0}).

Next I tried to subclass a UITextView and it increased this limit to about 300 characters, but still the same problem.

Anyone have any ideas about how I can increase this limit? I use up to 1000 characters.

My subclassed UITextView code is below (I know I've not completed the protocol bit yet but hopefully you get my issues...):

**ClickableTextView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ClickableTextViewDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void)hashTagPressed:(NSString*)hashtagName;
- (void)usernamePressed:(NSString*)username;

@end

@interface ClickableTextView : UITextView
{
    NSMutableArray *hashtags;
    NSMutableArray *usernames;
    UIColor *clickableColor;
    //id <ClickableTextViewDelegate> labelDelegate;
}

//@property (nonatomic,strong) id labelDelegate;

- (void)setClickableColor:(UIColor*)color;

@end
```

**ClickableTextView.m**

```
#import "ClickableTextView.h"

@implementation ClickableTextView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        clickableColor = [UIColor blueColor];

        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self.editable = NO;
        self.scrollEnabled = NO;
        self.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(respondToTapGesture:)];

        tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setText:(NSString*)text
{
    [super setText:text];

    NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];
    [self setAttributedText:attrString];

    if(!hashtags) {
        hashtags = [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    if(!usernames) {
        usernames = [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    [hashtags removeAllObjects];
    [usernames removeAllObjects];

    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"#(\\w+)" options:0 error:nil];
    NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, text.length)];
    for(NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
        NSRange tagRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
        tagRange.location--;
        tagRange.length++;

        [attrString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:clickableColor range:tagRange];

        CGRect tagRect = [self boundingRectForCharacterRange:tagRange];
        [hashtags addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[[text substringWithRange:tagRange], [NSNumber numberWithInt:tagRect.origin.x], [NSNumber numberWithInt:tagRect.origin.y], [NSNumber numberWithInt:tagRect.size.width], [NSNumber numberWithInt:tagRect.size.height]] forKeys:@[@"text", @"x", @"y", @"width", @"height"]]];
    }

    regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"@(\\w+)" options:0 error:nil];
    matches = [regex matchesInString:text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, text.length)];
    for(NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
        NSRange userRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
        userRange.location--;
        userRange.length++;

        [attrString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:clickableColor range:userRange];

        CGRect userRect = [self boundingRectForCharacterRange:userRange];
        [usernames addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[[text substringWithRange:userRange], [NSNumber numberWithInt:userRect.origin.x], [NSNumber numberWithInt:userRect.origin.y], [NSNumber numberWithInt:userRect.size.width], [NSNumber numberWithInt:userRect.size.height]] forKeys:@[@"text", @"x", @"y", @"width", @"height"]]];
    }

    [self setAttributedText:attrString];

    [self sizeToFit];
}

- (CGRect)boundingRectForCharacterRange:(NSRange)range
{
    NSTextStorage *textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:[self attributedText]];

    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
    [textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];

    NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:[self bounds].size];
    [layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];

    NSRange glyphRange;
    [layoutManager characterRangeForGlyphRange:range actualGlyphRange:&glyphRange];

    return [layoutManager boundingRectForGlyphRange:glyphRange inTextContainer:textContainer];
}

- (void)respondToTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
    CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:self];

    for(NSDictionary *hashtag in hashtags) {
        CGRect tagRect = CGRectMake([[hashtag objectForKey:@"x"] floatValue], [[hashtag objectForKey:@"y"] floatValue], [[hashtag objectForKey:@"width"] floatValue], [[hashtag objectForKey:@"height"] floatValue]);

        if(CGRectContainsPoint(tagRect, point)) {
            NSLog(@"Hashtag: %@", [hashtag objectForKey:@"text"]);
        }
    }

    for(NSDictionary *username in usernames) {
        CGRect userRect = CGRectMake([[username objectForKey:@"x"] floatValue], [[username objectForKey:@"y"] floatValue], [[username objectForKey:@"width"] floatValue], [[username objectForKey:@"height"] floatValue]);

        if(CGRectContainsPoint(userRect, point)) {
            NSLog(@"Username: %@", [username objectForKey:@"text"]);
        }
    }
}

- (void)setClickableColor:(UIColor*)color
{
    clickableColor = color;

    if(self.text) {
        [self setText:self.text];
    }
}

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    ClickableTextView *textView = [[ClickableTextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, self.view.frame.size.width - 100, 100)];
    textView.text = @"A #quick test. A quick test. A quick test. A quick test. A quick test. A quick test. A quick test. A quick test. A quick test. A quick test. A #quick test. A quick test. A quick test. A quick test. A quick test. A quick test. A quick test. A quick test. A quick test. A quick test. A quiiiiiiick #test";

    [self.view addSubview:textView];
}

@end
```

Please help!

Comment: Why not just use a `UIButton`?

Comment: Thanks for replying, Peter. The text is dynamic, so I never know where the clickable link will be. If I did do it that way I would still need to get the bounding CGRect of the hashtag/username text, and that's the part that's not working.

Comment: have you tried using IFTweetLabel..That makes hyperlinks to hashtags in the label

Comment: @Vidhyanand900, thanks for the heads up, but I was hoping to solve my problem. I want to do this myself, both so I can customise it in the future, and because I like to learn from my mistakes/shortcomings :) Any ideas?

Comment: @Damien did you work it out ? I'm facing the same question regards to the text view with constantly changed content too... my first thought is define keys of action : @, #, delete, return, plain text, and paste action, put them in json and stored in a mutable array with types : hashTag, userName, brakeLine and plainText. by switch last type in json and action to determine change the type, append string or delete the last json. I'm still trying, wish could hear from yours too :)

Comment: ooops, I just realizes your question isn't about inputing text, if you still need the solution,  there're many, like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25263607/1083128