# How to delete whole blocks of NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I am working on an app that lets the user mention other users by typing @*username*. Though I have [found a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24359972/detect-hash-tags-mention-tags-in-ios-like-in-twitter-app) to detect the @ character and highlight the selected username within the text string, I am not sure how to manage the event when the user mentions a user but then wants to delete that user from the mention.

For example, in the Facebook app, when you mention someone, that person's name in the UITextView is highlighted with a light-blue background. However, when you start deleting that mention, the whole mention gets deleted when you delete the last character in the attributed string.

I am, therefore, looking for a way that I can capture when the user deletes the last character of an attributed string in order to delete that whole attributed string and completely remove the mention from the text view.

Comment: How about subclassing `NSAttributedString` and add extra properties to capture the fact that the string contains a username?

Comment: i am also working on the @ flow can you help me out how deal with @taging ,both insert and delete the tag

Answer (score 3):

In order to achieve the desired behaviour mentioned above, I ended up doing the following. I implemented all these methods as part of the view controller where my UITextView is placed, so I added the *UITextViewDelegate* protocol to my view controller. Then, I implemented the following methods:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{
    //if this is true, then the user just deleted a character by using backspace
    if(range.length == 1 && text.length == 0){            
        NSUInteger cursorPosition = range.location; //gets cursor current position in the text
        NSRange attrRange; //will store the range of the text that holds specific attributes
        NSDictionary *attrs = [_content.attributedText attributesAtIndex:cursorPosition effectiveRange:&attrRange];

        //check if the attributes of the attributed text in the cursor's current position correspond to what you want to delete as a block
        if([attrs objectForKey:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName]){
            NSAttributedString *newStr = [_content.attributedText attributedSubstringFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, attrRange.location)]; //creates a new NSAttributed string without the block of text you wanted to delete
            _content.attributedText = newStr; //substitute the attributed text of your UITextView
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Luis Delgado's excellent answer gave me a great jumping off point, but has a few shortcomings:

- always clears to the end of the string
- does not handle insertion into the token
- does not handle modifying selected text that includes token(s)

Here is my version (Swift 4):

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    if range.location < textView.attributedText.length {

        var shouldReplace = false
        var tokenAttrRange = NSRange()
        var currentReplacementRange = range
        let tokenAttr = NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor

        if range.length == 0 {
            if nil != textView.attributedText.attribute(tokenAttr, at: range.location, effectiveRange: &tokenAttrRange) {
                currentReplacementRange = NSUnionRange(currentReplacementRange, tokenAttrRange)
                shouldReplace = true
            }
        } else {
            // search the range for any instances of the desired text attribute
            textView.attributedText.enumerateAttribute(tokenAttr, in: range, options: .longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired, using: { (value, attrRange, stop) in
                // get the attribute's full range and merge it with the original
                if nil != textView.attributedText.attribute(tokenAttr, at: attrRange.location, effectiveRange: &tokenAttrRange) {
                    currentReplacementRange = NSUnionRange(currentReplacementRange, tokenAttrRange)
                    shouldReplace = true
                }
            })
        }

        if shouldReplace {
            // remove the token attr, and then replace the characters with the input str (which can be empty on a backspace)
            let mutableAttributedText = textView.attributedText.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString
            mutableAttributedText.removeAttribute(tokenAttr, range: currentReplacementRange)
            mutableAttributedText.replaceCharacters(in: currentReplacementRange, with: text)
            textView.attributedText = mutableAttributedText

            // set the cursor position to the end of the edited location
            if let cursorPosition = textView.position(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, offset: currentReplacementRange.location + text.lengthOfBytes(using: .utf8)) {
                textView.selectedTextRange = textView.textRange(from: cursorPosition, to: cursorPosition)
            }

            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

If you need to override a superclass, add the override keyword and instead of returning true at the end, return

`super.textView(textView, shouldChangeTextIn: range, replacementText: text)`

You can change `tokenAttr` to any standard or custom text attribute. If you change enumerateAttribute to enumerateAttributes, you could even look for a combination of text attributes.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the entire `@username` surrounded with an attribute, subclass `UITextView` and override `-deleteBackward` to check if the cursor is inside one of the username attributes. If not, just call the super implementation, otherwise find the starting location and the length of the attributed username and delete the entire range.

Comment: This looks like a sensible approach to me. I was looking at utilising NSTextStorage, but looks like that would be unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: I took a different approach, but you pointed in the right direction. I'll share some code when I get back home.