# Detect hashtags and add to array

Tags: ios, swift, hashtag

I have a UITextField where the users can write a description.

Example: "This is a image of my #car. A cool #sunshine background also for my #fans."

How can i detect the hashtags "car", "sunshine" and "fans", and add them to a array?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk - Yes, i forgot that, but you still get my point?

Comment: Read this Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24359972/detect-hash-tags-mention-tags-in-ios-like-in-twitter-app

Answer (score 3):

```
let frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 30.0)

let description = UITextField(frame: frame)
description.text = "This is a image of my #car. A cool #sunshine background also for my #fans."


extension String {
    func getHashtags() -> [String]? {
        let hashtagDetector = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "#(\\w+)", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive)
        let results = hashtagDetector?.matchesInString(self, options: NSMatchingOptions.WithoutAnchoringBounds, range: NSMakeRange(0, self.utf16.count)).map { $0 }

        return results?.map({
            (self as NSString).substringWithRange($0.rangeAtIndex(1))
        })
    }
}

description.text?.getHashtags() // returns array of hashtags
```

Source: https://github.com/JamalK/Swift-String-Tools/blob/master/StringExtensions.swift

Comment: There's zero reasons to need to use a 3rd party piece of trash for something that is easy to do natively.

Comment: Here's the two calls you need to "hash tags" sh*t after finding these items using regular expressions. I'll never understand why you would need to use a Github piece of trash alternative to something that takes two lines of code to deploy:   [attString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:NSMakeRange(wordRange.location+1, wordRange.length-1)];
  [attString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value: @"http://www.google.com" range:wordRange];

Comment: @Larcerax - care to elaborate why your code snippet is a piece of art and the one posted above is sh*t?
Not sure if you understand what 3rd party really means.. your code is as 3rd party as the one posted above for anyone wanting to use it!

Comment: no, mine just uses IOS as apple wrote it, that's it, the methods for attributed string include NSUnderlineStyleSingle and NSLinkAttributeName then all you need is to RegEx into the hashtags, when the hastags are found, you add an underline, and you add the desired web link or in app link to a view controller. You intercept the messages sent by these hash tags using delegation in UITextVeiws that intercept text with NSLinkAttributeName attached to it, it's very very simple.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.2 version. At the end we return a list of hashtags/keywords without `#`.

```
extension String {
func getHashtags() -> [String]? {
    let hashtagDetector = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "#(\\w+)", options: NSRegularExpression.Options.caseInsensitive)

    let results = hashtagDetector?.matches(in: self, options: .withoutAnchoringBounds, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: count))

    return results?.map({
        (self as NSString).substring(with: $0.range(at: 1)).capitalized
    })
}
```

}

**e.g**

**Input**
`#hashtag1 #hashtag2 #hashtag3 #hashtag4 #hashtag5`

**Output**
`[hashtag1, hashtag2, hashtag3, hashtag4, hashtag5]`

Answer (score 0):

Check this pod: https://cocoapods.org/pods/twitter-text

In `TwitterText` class there is a method `(NSArray *)hashtagsInText:(NSString *)text checkingURLOverlap (BOOL)checkingURLOverlap`

Twitter created this pod for finding #, @, URLs so in my opinion there is no better way to do this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 version of @Anurag's answer:

```
extension String {
func getHashtags() -> [String]? {
    let hashtagDetector = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "#(\\w+)", options: NSRegularExpression.Options.caseInsensitive)
    let results = hashtagDetector?.matches(in: self, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions.withoutAnchoringBounds, range: NSMakeRange(0, self.characters.count)).map { $0 }

    return results?.map({
        (self as NSString).substring(with: $0.rangeAt(1))
    })
}
```

}